# Codeigniter Pagination over array instead of Database resultset

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have looked into trying to use the pagination class within codigniter but for my problem I need to paginate over an array of data and not a database table. In my code I create a custom array and then pass that array to the view using the standard

```
$this->load->vars($myarray);
$this->load->view('myview', $myarray);
```

Everything works fine in that sense but the $myarray at times can be really large. I really want to try and create some sort of pagination on the view that will only dislpay the first 25 of the array but the more I read about the Pagination class within codeigniter it looks like you can only paginate over database tables. Does anyone know how I might achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Table limits are used to paginate data as SQL allows you to explicitly avoid reading and processing data for pages that are not being displayed.  Loading an entire document into memory and showing only a subset of  pages using arrays implies reading and processing a much larger set of data, which will be difficult to scale.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just slice up the array yourself before loading it into the view?

https://www.php.net/array_slice
Give array_slice the page offset and result count and it will basically do exactly what you want.